# How to compare two array list object using linq in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to compare two array list object using jquery linq. I want to get matched array only.

```
array1 = [{ 'Id': '1', 'ReportName': Action Log', 'ACL': 'UserActionLog' }];

 array2 = [{ 'Id': '1', 'ReportName': Action Log', 'ACL': 'UserActionLog' },
{ 'Id': '2', 'ReportName': 'Audit Report', 'ACL': 'AuditReport' },
{ 'Id': '3', 'ReportName': 'User Log', 'ACL': 'User Log' },
{ 'Id': '4', 'ReportName': 'Report', 'ACL': 'Report' },
{ 'Id': '5', 'ReportName': 'User Action', ACL': 'User Action' },
{ 'Id': '6', 'ReportName': Dashboard', 'ACL': 'Dashboard' }]

result = [{ 'Id': '1', 'ReportName': Action Log', 'ACL': 'UserActionLog' }]
```

Comment: To start with, the array you have is not correct and Jquery Linq is not going to pass it

Comment: I edited the tags. The [linq] tag explicitly pertains to LINQ in .Net, not to LINQ-like extensions in javascript. Also, you're not really asking a question. Where do you experience problems?

Answer (score 0):

```
 array1 = [{ 'Id': '1', 'ReportName': 'Action Log', 'ACL': 'UserActionLog' 
 }];

 array2 = [{ 'Id': '1', 'ReportName': 'Action Log', 'ACL': 'UserActionLog' 
 },
 { 'Id': '2', 'ReportName': 'Audit Report', 'ACL': 'AuditReport' },
 { 'Id': '3', 'ReportName': 'User Log', 'ACL': 'User Log' },
 { 'Id': '4', 'ReportName': 'Report', 'ACL': 'Report' },
 { 'Id': '5', 'ReportName': 'User Action', 'ACL': 'User Action' },
 { 'Id': '6', 'ReportName': 'Dashboard', 'ACL': 'Dashboard' }]


var result = array1.filter(function(arr1) {
       return array2.some(function(arr2) {
       return arr1.Id=== arr2.Id && arr1.ReportName === arr2.ReportName && 
             arr1.ACL=== arr2.ACL;
  });
})

console.log(result);
```